# Ruby on Rails Active Storage validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

Is it possible to easily disable model validation only when attaching files? We have lots of data from our previous system that won't pass new validation rules and we can't attach any files to those. I know we could make another set of validation rules based on creation date (to allow older not not so good data) but we have dozens of different models so it wouldn't make sense to duplicate everything and up keeping the code would become very messy. And when normally updating some old data we still would want to use the new validation rules anyway.

Normally I can skip validations using .save(validate: false) but that approach doesn't seem to work when attaching files. We are using Ruby on Rails 6.